# Building alfresco.war and share.war using alfresco All-in-one (wars)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

I have went through the [Alfresco All-In-One sdk steps](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/alfresco-sdk-tutorials-all-in-one-archetype.html) and I am able to generate the share.war but not able to generate alfresco.war. It shows only the folder structure as shown in above site.

1. How can I generate alfresco.war?
2. Whats repo.war?
3. How to test that the share.war and alfresco.war are properly build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Repo" means "repository" and Alfresco is a repository. The WAR that gets created by default matches the directory that project is sitting in, which is called "repo" which is why the WAR is called "repo.war". So "repo.war" can be deployed to your Tomcat server and renamed to "alfresco.war" as they are the same.

You can add your own unit tests to your Alfresco SDK project if you'd like. But there are no standard unit tests that ship with the SDK.

Opinions differ about this, but I would not deploy the WAR files produced by the All-in-One project. Instead, move your AMPs to the server, then use the MMT to install them. That way, you are just testing your local AMPs and you know those work and you have less to move.

Comment: Few more query so by AMPs you mean repo-amp and share-amp folders to be moved to server. Also What is MMT?

Comment: If you have a link to some tutorial then please share it. Thank you again!

Comment: I have created the extension using AIO and followed this (link)[http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-quick-start.html] then I put the alfresco.war(repo) and share.war in webapps of tomcat folder created. but when I run the server, it shows default alfresco community page

Comment: is your url is this ? localhost:8080/share

Comment: AMPs are not runnable. They need to be merged with your Alfresco and Share WARs. The way you do that is with the Module Management Tool, also known as the MMT. In your Alfresco install, you should have an amps directory and an amps_share directory. Place your amps in their respective directory, then from ALFRESCO_HOME run bin/apply_amps.sh to merge your AMPs with the Alfresco and Share WARs. Then you can start Tomcat.

Comment: @JeffPotts Thanks.. will try this out !